# Apply Skrollr to dynamic loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, plugins, skrollr

I have a page which has several posts in it where skrollr applies and works correctly.

```
var s = skrollr.init();
```

One of the functionalities of the page is to load dynamically the content of one of the posts. I am doing this with jQuery and Ajax. After the content is retrieved I insert it in the page. This new content has data tags that refer to skrollr. Therefore I call

```
s.refresh();
```

after the content is inserted with a timeout just in case. But Im not getting skrollr to work with the new (dynamic) inserted content.
Note:If I navigate to the individual page of the post skrollr works correctly there.

I want to know if the way of approaching the problem is correct or I am missing or doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to do this as suggested here: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/450

I am not sure if it is the best way to solve it.

When the ajax call is made I destroy the skrollr:

```
s.destroy();
```

and after the dynamic content is inserted I create a new instance of skrollr again:

```
s = skrollr.init();
```

Comment: The better way is `s.refresh();`